# How can I add a default library path?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I've received some projects from a 3rd party that contain a lot of references to packages (DLLs) that aren't found. All of these packages are in a folder on my system. How do I configure Visual C# Express to find them automatically?

I'm not sure of the C# terminology -- are they libraries, packages or something else? They are DLL files with names like *Client.namespace.detail.dll*.

Comment: After poking around some more I've found a partial solution. The properties page for the project includes a "Reference Paths" tab. Adding the folder there resolved all of the assemblies but one. Odd, because that dll is in there. I would really like to add that reference path to ALL projects as a default setting, as there may be many using those assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies. And they should be linked from a folder in the same level as the project - in the solution.

That would be a relative link and go into source control with the project.

Comment: Assemblies... right. But is there no way to tell the IDE where to look without adding them again? I think that's what you are suggesting. I don't have to update the reference to System.Core, for example. The IDE knows where to look.

Comment: System.Core is GAC. Adding assmeblies to GAC without reason is non-sensible - thre are security issues.